# cannot group by the data

Tags: sql, oracle

Input

```
A   B    date
--------------------
00  12   22-01-2019
00  12   null
00  25   22-01-2019
00  24   22-01-2019
```

From the above data I need the following output:

```
  A   B    date
--------------------
 00  12    null
 00  25    22-01-2019
 00  24   22-01-2019
```

I need to get open,closed records from the table.

if i used date is null then other records existing will not appear.

i need to apply condition in Column B.

If Column there is null value in date for column B then null will show
otherwise if there both null and not null value null then date null will be output.

```
Select a,b,date 
from table1,table2
where ...
group by a,b,date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate functions ignores nulls so you need [anaytic version](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm):

```
select a, b, min(date_) keep (dense_rank first order by date_ nulls first) 
  from input group by a, b
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=122ad0a22882ee65c6299bd20cc43c63)</sup>**

Comment: This is a nice solution. One side note: when you just use `KEEP( ... )` its still an aggregation function; you would need to add the window clause (`OVER( [PARTITION BY ... ] [ORDER BY ...] )`) to change it to an analytic function.

Comment: Hi ponder there is req change - get latest date .  please can you help https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d225db3209346008a82d08155eb27b8a

Comment: Look at [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3f8f4e3d5e08bc6d383028cf348c9db6). In case there are only not null dates for tuple (a, b) it returns highest. If at least one is null then returns null.

Answer (score 2):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( A, B, DT ) AS
SELECT 0, 12, DATE '2019-01-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 12, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 25, DATE '2019-01-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 24, DATE '2019-01-22' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT A,
       B,
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT( CASE WHEN DT IS NULL THEN 1 END ) > 0
       THEN NULL
       ELSE MAX( DT )
       END AS DT
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY A, B;
```

**Output**:

```
 A |  B | DT       
-: | -: | :--------
 0 | 12 | null     
 0 | 24 | 22-JAN-19
 0 | 25 | 22-JAN-19
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=84f9ec5e449e0ddfd48c0592799c50bf)*